# Where is the story of Dhritarashtra removing eyes of swan mentioned?

Tags: mahabharata

I have read that the blindness of Dhritarashtra is due to his actions in previous birth. He removed the eyes of a swan and killed hundred cygnets. But I couldn´t find this story in Mahabharatha. Where can I find it in Mahabharata? Can anybody help?